# FileNotFoundException thrown when calling Assembly.GetExportedTypes()

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, x86, vmware-workstation, windows-xp-sp2

I'm getting this error when running a .net 2.0 app on a stripped-down XP SP3 x86 virtual machine, even if .net 2.0 framework runtime has already been installed prior to installing the app.

```
Exception Source:      mscorlib
Exception Type:        System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Exception Message:     Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception Target Site: GetExportedTypes

---- Stack Trace ----
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
       XSplit.Core.exe: N 00000
   XSplit.Core.Capture.ChannelAddinManager.#Dm( As String)
       XSplit.Core.exe: N 00105
   XSplit.Core.Capture.ChannelAddinManager.#Cm()
       XSplit.Core.exe: N 00265
   XSplit.Core.Capture.ChannelAddinManager.Init(path As String, host As IAddinHost)
       XSplit.Core.exe: N 00104
   XSplit.Core.frmLogin.InitializeAddinComponent()
       XSplit.Core.exe: N 00534
   XSplit.Core.frmLogin..ctor(args As String[])
       XSplit.Core.exe: N 01263
```

The related code that spawns this error is this

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFile);
var assemblyTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
```

Even after installing framework 2.0 sp2, this error is still thrown.

You guys got any clue on why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WindowsBase assembly didn't become available until .NET 3.0.  If you want to run this code without an exception then you'll need to install 3.0 on the machine, 2.0 isn't good enough.  Check the build settings for the add-in project and make sure that it doesn't reference any WPF assemblies.

Comment: The build target is .net 2.0 and none of the assemblies referenced are WPF, so we're baffled as to why this error would be thrown.